# Can I use logistic regression for non binary explained variable (e.g. 0.1, 0.7) and how?

Tags: logistic

Can I use logistic regression for non binary explained variable (e.g. 0.1, 0.7)? How the procedure is different from the normal case?

Comment: Please say more about your explained variable. Is it a proportion? Does it take on only a few values? Is it continuous but bounded? Or what?

Comment: It is between 0 and 1 (both values are included). It is continuous, but bounded

Comment: A variable that attains just two values, such as $0.1$ and $0.7,$ is *a fortiori* a binary variable.  Could you therefore clarify what you mean by "e.g. 0.1, 0.7"?

Comment: I just meant that the variable will be continuous

Answer (score 1):

I assume your explained variable is a fraction and bounded between 0 and 1. In that case your logit model - with robust standard errors, or equivalently, estimated by maximizing the Quasi-likelihood - would become a fractional logit model. How it is different from a regular logit model is a bit of an open ended question. You could write a book on that. I recently wrote a encyclopedia entry on that topic, that should get you started: http://www.maartenbuis.nl/publications/prop.html